# Windows Azure application in Java and JSF

Tags: java, jsf, cloud

I wrote web application using JSF, xhtml, CSS and Apache Tomcat in Eclipse and I want to start it on Windows Azure emulator. I installed "Windows Azure plugin for eclipse" ([here is instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944%28VS.103%29.aspx)). 
When I choose option "Package for Windows Azure" and I want to run application on WA emulator everything is ok - I see information on console "BUILD SUCCESSFUL", server started etc. But when I type application url adress on web browser, it displays

> HTTP status 404 The requested resource (/ChatAzure/) is not available.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your app might not be getting into Tomcat's webapps. One way to troubleshoot is AFTER you try to run it in the emulator, go into your Azure project's "deploy" folder, navigate the folder hierarchy until you get to the specific role folder (like WorkerRole1 if using default names) go inside approot, find the tomcat folder in there, and look into its webapps folder. You can see the effects of your deployment logic this way. If your app isn't inside webapps, there may be an app deployment problem.
(The actual directories may be different depending on how you've customized the deployment logic)